# Most viewed questions in the last "number" of days

Tags: support, statistics, data-explorer

Hi :) This might not be easy.

I want a list of the **currently** most viewed questions; in the past "number" of days for example. Not all time views. Not like [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/82571/top-x-viewed-questions) (although it's very close). For example "in the past week; the questions so and so and so and so were viewed most".

By the way I'm in severe need of such list!!!! Not just for fun believe it or not.

I tried searching data explorer a bit but I couldn't find or make "the query". It's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: The 10k tools has something like that, but is limited to today, 2 last days, 7 days, 14 days and 30 days.

Comment: @braiam what is the 10k tools? or where can I find it? I don't understand. ...Thanks so far

Comment: The 10k tools are a set of tools given to users with 10,000 reputation or more. They're useful for monitoring the site at a high level like that.

Comment: oh oh okay! I had a really different approach towards the sentence! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [forked Marco's query to allow you to specify the CreationDate](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/revision/179545/230654/top-x-viewed-questions-for-the-last-y-days). That should do what you were asking. You could add a minimum age parameter too.

I'd suggest learning a bit of SQL is you want to get the best out of Data.SE. It's a good tool but it can get pretty hairy if you're not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I wish I'd learn too. I'd love to. I'm asking for help because I'm illiterate :(  ...anyway, I'm sorry that's not what I'm asking for.  Actually I wouldn't benefit much from recent questions. Look; I'm asking for questions that have had the maximum "**increase in view count**" in the past "month". Not maximum "view count" in the past month. That's a different number! ...Do you know a way to lay our hands that number? That's what's hard about my question

Comment: "the rate of change"

Comment: *lay our hands on that number. stupid typo -_-

Comment: I see... As far as I know there isn't access to historical data like that.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :( ...well thanks you so much :D